# "diff" terabyte files

Tags: diff

Are there any tools that allow to "diff" text files of terabyte size?

Comment: What kind of differences are you anticipating? Small differences on otherwise similar lines, or large chunks added or removed?

Comment: Voting to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bdiff`](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517082612/http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/unix/solaris-10-11_06/1/bdiff-man-page.html). It is used to compare files that are too large to be loaded in memory.

```
NAME
     bdiff - big diff

SYNOPSIS
     bdiff filename1 filename2 [n] [-s]

DESCRIPTION
     bdiff is used in a manner analogous to diff  to  find  which
     lines  in  filename1  and filename2 must be changed to bring
     the files into agreement. Its purpose is to allow processing
     of  files too large for diff. If filename1 (filename2) is -,
     the standard input is read.
```

Comment: That will work well for scattered small changes. Because it works by splitting the input into chunks and diffing corresponding chunks, i think it will do a pretty bad job on inputs which differ with large insertions or deletions. Still the best suggestion so far, though!

Comment: the link has been dead. I've updated it for you. Or use alternate man pages like https://www.unix.com/man-page/ultrix/1/bdiff/, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/bdiff-1.html

Answer (score -1):

Are the files sortable? (e.g. via "sort" command)

If they are, and depending on the kind of difference you are looking for and if this is a once-off exercise, why don't you sort them each, split into the letters of the alphabet (or whatever, as long as you get multiple files) and then compare each letter..

Primitive, but might work neat and easily for you?